# Are elements not "reachable" from 0 prevented in Peano Arithmetic?

Tags: peano-axioms

I am having a [discussion](http://www.fimfiction.net/blog/255726/sex-violence-and-meaning#comment/1606757) about Peano Arithmetic and I was told that there is actually nothing in Peano Arithmetic to prevent one from defining an element a with S^k(a)=a.
I am only able to derive that a is not S^j(0) for any j, but I don't see how that is a problem for introducing a in the first place.
If introducing those elements is actually possible, there are some neat properties with those.

Comment: Nothing except the induction axiom scheme.

Comment: As to non-reachability, which is very different from invariant under some iterated successor, certainly the axioms of first-order PA have models that, beside the ordinary natural numbers, have "non-standard" elements.

Comment: Ah, good, those "non-standard" elements I am interested in. Are there any sources on that? I was told about one such element a for which S(a)=a that can be used as one would expect infinity to work.

Comment: That is second-order PA. Second-order PA is categorical, it has up to isomorphism only one model, so the comment above does not apply to it.

Comment: We **cannot** get $Sa=a$ holding in any model of PA (either version). For "non-standard models of arithmetic" Google that and relatives, you will get lots of hits.

Comment: Why? I don't see why S(a)=a should be forbidden. I mean, which axioms does it contradict and how? Is there a proof for ￢(S(a)=a) in first-order PA?

Comment: Yes, there is a proof. The proof given in the answer by universal set can be adapted to show that for any fixed positive integer $k$, $S^k(a)=a$ has no solution. That's beasically because for any fixed $k$, the assertion of non-solvability can be stated as a sentence of first-order PA, and first-order induction gives a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\lnot \exists a S(a)=a$ you appeal to the induction hypothesis.  We have $\lnot S(0)=0$  Then assuming $\lnot S(n)=n$ we have $\lnot S(S(n))=S(n)$  From that we conclude $\forall n \lnot S(n)=n$  This is typical of the non-standard elements.  Any property shared by all the standard elements (or even all sufficiently large ones) is shared by all the non-standards.  This style of proof shows that.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thank you very much! Seems I underestimated the ramifications of the induction axiom.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth expanding on André Nicolas's comment above.  For any (standard) natural number $k>0$, one can show in Peano Arithmetic that there is no element $a$ such that $S^k(a) = a$.  Why?  Certainly this is true for $a=0$, since $0$ is not a successor, and since successor is injective, if $S^k(b) \neq b$, then $S^k(S(b)) = S(S^k(b)) \neq S(b)$, so we have a proof that if $b$ satisfies $\phi(x) = (x \neq S^k(x))$ then $S(b)$ does as well.  This, of course, is exactly what is needed to apply the induction axiom for $\phi$ and hence there is no such $a$ with $S^k(a) = a$.

There are, however, plenty of non-standard models of Peano Arithmetic; in such models there are "unreachable" elements, that is, elements $a$ such that $a$ is not $S^n(0)$ for any (standard) natural number $n$.

Comment: Well, it is exactly these non-standard models I am interested in. I wrote: "I am only able to derive that a is not S^j(0) for any j, but I don't see how that is a problem for introducing a in the first place".

Comment: The proof above (in the first paragraph) is a proof in Peano Arithmetic and does not rely on being a standard model; it applies just as well to non-standard models of PA.